# Multi-label grouping with SQL query

Tags: sql, multilabel-classification

I want to be able to go through a list of multi-labeled entries, where I can find data on common groups of labels.
I have a table structured as the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|GameID |   Title   |Label1 |Label2 |Label3 |Label4 |...    |LabelN |
|-------|-----------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|1      |   A       |   1   |   0   |   1   |   0   |   ... |   1   |   
|2      |   B       |   1   |   1   |   0   |   1   |   ... |   0   |
|3      |   C       |   0   |   0   |   1   |   1   |   ... |   0   |
|4      |   D       |   1   |   0   |   0   |   0   |   ... |   1   |
|...    |   ...     |   ... |   ... |   ... |   ... |   ... |   ... |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If an entry has a one under the label, that means that entry is associated with that label. Otherwise, it is not associated with that lable. For example, game A has the labels "Label1", "Label3", ..., and "LabelN" associated to it.

Now, take for example this SQL query:

```
SELECT GameID, Title
FROM GameTagsBinary
WHERE "Gun Customization" = 1 AND "Zombies" = 1
```

This query would return the following table:

```
-------------------------------------
|GameID |   Title                   |
|-------|---------------------------|
|263070 |   Blockstorm              |
|209870 |   Blacklight: Retribution |
|436520 |   Line of Sight           |
-------------------------------------
```

What I would like is to have a query that will go through every column, Label1 through LabelN, and print out the number of games that correlate with those labels.

```
-------------------------------------------------
|Combination                |   NumberOfGames   |
|---------------------------|-------------------|   
|Label1 + Label2            |   5               |
|Label1 + Label3            |   11              |
|Label1 + Label4            |   9               |
|...                        |   ...             |
|Gun Customization + Zombies|   3               |
|...                        |   ...             |
|LabelN + Label(N-1)        |   7               |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Gun Customization and Zombies are the column's name ? and also, how you define the combination of labels for checking?

Comment: It seems you need an extra table for defining the combination of labels for checking. Or you just want to check every combination of columns?

Comment: ProgrammingBaKa, yes "Gun Customization" and "Zombies" are the column's name. I was wondering if there was a for, or for each loop to go through a data frame's columns. That way, I can have one loop to go through the columns, and a nested loop to find the combinations, preferably only the unique combination and no redundancy.  Wanting just to try two label combinations, but then see if I can do three or four combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below logic, (Replace YOUR_TABLE_NAME with your actual table name)

You probably need to create a stored procedure to run SQL script for getting the result.

Btw, the code is for SQL server, if you use other database, some of the code will be different.

**Code finding distinct combination of columns**

```
select result.* into #temp from (
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by a.name) as id, a.name as a_name, b.name as b_name from 
(select name from sys.columns where object_id=object_id('YOUR_TABLE_NAME')) a
 cross join
(select name from sys.columns where object_id=object_id('YOUR_TABLE_NAME')) b
where a.name <> b.name ) result

select a_name, b_name into #combination from #temp temp1 where not exists(select 1 from #temp temp2 where temp1.a_name = temp2.b_name and temp1.b_name = temp2.a_name and temp1.id > temp2.id)
```

**Cursor loop through combination and insert into another temp table**

```
create table #result
(
    Combination varchar(100),
    NumberOfGames int
)

DECLARE @a_name varchar(100);
DECLARE @b_name varchar(100);
DECLARE @combination_string varchar(100);
DECLARE @count int;
DECLARE @count_sql varchar(1000);
DECLARE combo_cursor CURSOR FOR select a_name, b_name FROM #combination
OPEN combo_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM combo_cursor INTO @a_name, @b_name;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    set @combination_string = @a_name + ' + ' + @b_name

    set @sql = 'select @count = count(*) from YOUR_TABLE_NAME where ' + @a_name + ' = 1 and ' + @b_name + ' = 1'

    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql

    insert into #result (Combination, NumberOfGames)
    values (@combination_string, @count)

    FETCH NEXT FROM combo_cursor INTO @a_name, @b_name;
END

CLOSE combo_cursor;
DEALLOCATE combo_cursor;
```

**your final result**

```
select * from #result
```

**drop temp table after execution**

```
drop table #temp
drop table #combination
drop table #result
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `count()` parameter in your select statement?

ie.

`Select count(*) 
    From GameTagsBinary 
    Where Label1 = "Gun Customization" AND Label2 = "Zombies"`

However i am unsure how to do this for all your labels in one go, i assume might be able to do it in one massive query with lots of joins. Sorry i can't help more but this should be able to help a bit.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, this does help me with one aspect of my problem. Now I am getting a table with the following query:

`SELECT count(*) AS "Gun_Customization.Zombies"
FROM GameTagsBinary
WHERE "Gun Customization" = 1 AND "Zombies" = 1`

`Gun_Customization.Zombies
3`

Comment: The thing is, there are roughly 300 labels, and I don't want to make 45,000 queries. However, I can easily make a long query from excel. The thing is, how would I divide the conditions in the WHERE section such that each entry will have a name for the tag combination? Or is there a more autonomous approach, rather than hard coding in the labels for the conditions?

Comment: @LawrenceJacobKlinkert Right, i dont know how to do this without manually putting in the conditions, your comment about using a `For` loop makes sense, however i am probably more inexperienced in coding than you. As far as i know the `For` loop should look like this

    `For each "Column Name/Variable" in "Tablename"
   Where "Column1 and Column2" = 1
count = count + 1`

Where you want to loop this through each row as well. So i guess the idea is, 1. Loop through columns which = 1, 2. Loop and count rows which have columns that = 1, group the ones which have the same columns = 1.